# Clipping raster with Postgis raster

Tags: postgis, raster, clip, raster2pgsql

I'm using Postgis 2.1.5 on Ubuntu 15.04. In my system there is a second disk mounted with the raster data as `/media/name1/data/rasters/*.tif`.

The `*.tif` are good looking when I watch the metadata with `gdalinfo`.

The data is imported into the raster data table with `raster2pgsql` without problems.

Variables for raster support are set in the PostGIS enviroment file correctly.

When I want to clip the raster data by:

```
SELECT ST_Clip(a.rast,b.geom) 
FROM public.raster a, public.umringe b 
WHERE a.filename = b.datei_bez;
```

The following error is the result :

> ERROR:  rt_band_load_offline_data: Cannot open offline raster: /media/ausbild/2ndDrive/Geodaten/Komserv/Daten/LK_WIL/Work/test/raster_new/BPlan.07231001.2.0.plan.tif
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_clip(raster,integer[],geometry,double precision[],boolean) line 8 at RETURN
>   ********** Fehler **********
>
> ERROR: rt_band_load_offline_data: Cannot open offline raster: /media/ausbild/2ndDrive/Geodaten/Komserv/Daten/LK_WIL/Work/test/raster_new/BPlan.07231001.2.0.plan.tif
>   SQL Status:XX000
>   Kontext:PL/pgSQL function st_clip(raster,integer[],geometry,double precision[],boolean) line 8 at RETURN

I tested it with the referenced file on the "normal" home-path, and then it works. But for the work with the whole 45GB of raster-data the volume is not big enough, so I have to use the "external" media drive.

Comment: Is your out-db raster flag enabled? See this page: http://postgis.net/2015/05/02/tip_enable_raster_drivers/

Comment: Yes, I enabled out-db and gdal drivers in the documented way !  In spite of all these setting, it won't work for my described architecture til now.

Comment: Can postgres read the location?

Comment: I set the rhigt's in my linux system up to 777 for the path.

Comment: Could you share the raster2pgsql command that you used? It might give clues.

Comment: raster2pgsql -s 31466 -I -C -M -R -F -c -l4 /media/xy/yx/*.tif public.raster | psql -d mydb2clip -U postgres

Comment: Seems like you did everything correct. Last thing I can think about is that somewhere in that path there is still a directory not accessible. You can check by doing a 'sudo su postgres' en then try to access that location.

Comment: When I put the files to my home path, it works without problems. Why ?

Comment: Did you check if the postgres user can access like i suggested in the prev comment?